# Returning a boolean from a method with an asynchronous (AJAX) call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a calendar app where I have an array of dates:

```
<div v-for="date in dates">{{ date }}</div>
```

and I'm trying to add a conditional class based on the result of an *isWeekend()* method making an API call:

```
<div v-for="date in dates" :class="[(isWeekend) ? 'weekend' : '']>{{ date }}</div>
```

The method makes an AJAX request, and needs to return true/false, but naturally the async call finishes after the method returns:

```
methods: {
  isWeekend(date) {
     let thisIsAWeekend = false
     axios.get('http://myapi/' + date).then(response => { 
       if (...) thisIsAWeekend = true
     })
     return thisIsAWeekend // <-- always returns false
  }
}
```

I've tried a setTimeout around the return, to give the API call time to resolve, but the method still always returns false.

How can I apply a conditional class determined by an API call?

*Note: I realize I can use JS' `getDay()`, e.g., to determine a weekend... this is a bit of a contrived example to demonstrate the technical issue.*

Answer (score 1):

The words `return` and `async` should not be used together.  Because of its asynchronous nature, the method shouldn't be expected to return something. The logical thing to do is to extract the information from the async call once it has completed the work. With promises, there is a `then` callback function which is called upon completion of the request. You can change the value to your boolean here (it implies higher scope for the variable), or beter yet, you can emit an event that the value has changed, and all the listeners will know about the change.

Answer (score 0):

An async call doesn't return a result, even if you wait for it. It returns a promise. You can't use a promise in your template, you need an actual value.

The most straightforward thing to do would be to make a component that takes `date` as a prop and has a `watch` on it to make the axios call and populate an `isWeekend` data item in the component.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid such a refactor, but given the circumstances, and the increasing complexity of each <date>, that might be the most sensible route.